# Fit QWidget to QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I need to make the QWidget the same size as parent QGraphicsScene even on resizing the dock widget.

[image: pic]

```
ui->w1_move->setParent(NULL);

view1 = new QGraphicsView(this);
scene1 = new QGraphicsScene(this);

view1->setScene(scene1);
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pwig = scene1->addWidget(ui->w1_move);
ui->dockWidgetContents->layout()->addWidget(view1);
```

EDIT:
Complete code here: [github](https://github.com/pazduha/GrapScene)

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Link to complete example...

Answer (score 0):

i added a custom resize:

```
void MyGraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    scn->setSceneRect(0,0,event->size().width(),event->size().height());
    wig->resize(event->size());


    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```